# BEGIN and END causing syntax error in gawk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

`BEGIN` and `END` are causing syntax errors in my pretty simple script.

The general outline of the script is:

```
args=("$0")
gawk -v var=0 '{
 *do stuff based on input file
 *stuff gets assigned to var
 *END{ print var}
}' ${args[0]}
```

I get the following error, and I have no idea why:

```
gawk: cmd. line:x:    END { ... }
gawk: cmd. line:x:    ^ syntax error
```

EDIT:
So Adam Liss was right!  I had an error with my curly braces.

What I was essentially doing was gawk '{script END{stuff}}' when I should've been doing gawk'{script}END{stuff}'

Thanks Adam!

Comment: I think we'll have to see your "*do stuff based on input file", or a trimmed-down version that still gives you the same error.

Comment: You'll most likely get better answers if you post a real script that demonstrates the problem. (It doesn't have to be *your* actual script, but it does have to be something that can be run.)

Comment: I don't think you want to enclose your entire script within curly braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
args=("$0")
gawk -v var=0 '{
 #do stuff based on input file
 #stuff gets assigned to var
}
END{ print var}' ${args[0]}
```